# PHP:Uploaded File not move to folder (CLOSED)

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello i have one problem to ask. The problem is when i'm trying to upload an image to certain folder usin php, the image is not move.The image information is insert into database but only the image is not move to destination folder. The folder is empty but no error is show. My file_upload in Php.ini is on but still the image is not move.
Below is my code:

```
<form action='try1.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<table border='1'><tr>
   <td><input type='file' name='file_img' /></td><td>
   <input type='submit' name='btn_upload' value='upload'></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php

    require 'conf.php';

    $link = mysqli_connect($h,$u,$p,$db);
    if(isset($_POST['btn_upload']))
     {
      $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"];
      $filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"];
      $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"];
      $filepath = "upload/".$filename;

      move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);


     $query = "insert into try (image,type,path) values ('$filename','$filetype','$filepath')";
     $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);


    }
 ?>
```

I hope some one can help me to solve this problem,thank you.

(solved)I have solved the problem. its not the code but my pc that have problem.Thank you for helping.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Where have you looked for errors? The apache log files? I suspect permission issues. `chown apache:apache /path/to/destination -R`

Comment: move_uploaded_file returns true/false on success/failure. Save it to a temporary variable and output/log it. More than likely it's a permission issue.

Answer (score 2):

At first delete your upload folder. After that
Please keep below code in your code.

```
  $filepath = "upload/";
  $filePathWithFileName = "upload/".$filename;

  if (!file_exists($filepath)) {
        mkdir($filepath, 0777);
  } 

  move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filePathWithFileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

$filepath = "./upload/".$filename;